# ReactJS: Trying to get values inside an array inside of state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

So, I am using antd to handle a Form component that has an initial state like this:

```
...constructor
...super
state = { 
  tags: ["tag"]
}

handleSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(this.state);
  // gives me Object { tags: [] }
}

render() {
  return <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
}
```

This is literally it... but I have no idea why I keep getting an empty array in console. Maybe this is impossible to figure out with this much info, but that's why it's driving me insane. I have noticed that if I comment out some code in this class, that it will all of sudden start showing the array values... no idea.

Any help would be appreciated.

When I go into the React Devtools, it shows the "tag" in my tags array. But, when I hit submit, it clears the array. I'm guessing this is tied in somehow, but I'm not sure why the state is clearing just the tags array and not the other state values. Something to do with a deep clone... ?

Comment: "I have noticed that if I comment out some code in this class, that it will all of sudden start showing the array values... no idea.". Can you post the class code or more of those lines?

Comment: Okay, I have narrowed it down... looks like it has to do with this line: `this.props.form.validateFields(err => {`

Comment: And, the form prop comes in from `export const WrappedExpenseForm = Form.create()(ExpenseForm);`

Comment: Which, I'm guessing is just making a shallow copy of the state of the child component...

Comment: Please make a **producible example** [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For setup default values in ant design form and after validate you need to follow the required steps:

1. Wrap form:

```
class YouComponent extends Component { //..... }

const WrappedComponent = Form.create({ name: 'you_form' })(YouComponent);

export default WrappedComponent;
```

2. To setup default values:

> in you case i think you can use the `Select` component for `tags`

```
 <Form layout="inline" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <Form.Item>
      {getFieldDecorator("tags", {
        rules: [{ required: true, message: "Pleases select tag!" }]
      })(
        <Select
          mode="multiple"
          style={{ width: "100%" }}
          placeholder="Please select"
          // here setup default selected of tags
          defaultValue={this.state.tags}
        >
          {// map here tags <Select.Option>}
        </Select>
      )}
    </Form.Item>
  </Form>
```

> Select [documentation](https://ant.design/components/select/#header)

3. To validate and get value from form:

```
handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log("Received values of form: ", values);
      }
    });
  };
```